# Trouble getting desired hover state

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

There is a section on the site I'm working on that has images within a container. I need to add a hover state to the images that displays a white square with a thin border within the container over the image (screenshot below). The reason I am having trouble with this is because I already have a box-shadow over the image. I tried adding one to the other elements surrounding the image, but haven't been successful. If anyone could help out that would be great!

What it looks like:

[image]

Desired effect on hover:

[image]

HTML:

```css
    .opinion .atable .acell {
      display: table-cell;
      height: 100%;
      width: 25%;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-radius: 3px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
      -moz-border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: #fff;
      outline: none;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell:hover {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
      box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell .contentbox {
      position: relative;
    }
    .slideImg {
      display: none;
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul {
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a {
      color: white;
      display: block;
      height: 200px;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(131, 141, 142, 0.7) inset;
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a span {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
      color: #fff;
      z-index: 10;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 1.3em;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
      border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    }
    .opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 350px blue;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="opinion">
  <div class="atable">
    <div class="acell">

      <div class="contentbox">

        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <a href="www.google.com" title="Permalink to Broadway Project" style="box-shadow: rgba(131, 140, 142, 0.701961) 0px 0px 0px 100px inset; background-image: url('http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg');">
              <img src="http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg" class="slideImg wp-post-image" alt="broadwayproject2"><span>Broadway Project</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question would become answerable if you replaced the `php` code with its result. Copy paste the `HTML` markup from the page's source. Right click > View source > {find the elements, copy as html} and replace the code in your question with that one. Please do not copy/paste more than the [minimal necessary markup](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the behaviour. Link stylesheets if you have to.

Comment: I edited your code as snippet. I also wrapped the `html` in `.opinion` and `.atable`, as otherwise most of your CSS would not have applied. Could you provide a link to the `style.css` of your theme (and of your parent theme if you have one), so i can add it/them to the snippet and see all code that applies? *Note: You might not see the change until it gets [looked at](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10517301) by a moderator.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you wanted?

I have placed my CSS above yours, no need to copy yours once more in the project. And, by the way, there's an error in your CSS (`-moz-border-radius-topleft` should be `-moz-border-top-left-radius`)

```css
div.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul {
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 40px;
  widows: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.slides:hover:after {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  left: 9px;
  top: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid white;
  content: ' ';
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul.slides a>span {
  display: none;
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul.slides:hover a>span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* code under this line is already in the project, you don't need it */

.opinion .atable .acell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.opinion .atable .acell:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 7px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox {
  position: relative;
}
.slideImg {
  display: none;
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(131, 141, 142, 0.7) inset;
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.opinion .atable .acell .contentbox ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 350px blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="opinion">
  <div class="atable">
    <div class="acell">

      <div class="contentbox">

        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <a href="www.google.com" title="Permalink to Broadway Project" style="box-shadow: rgba(131, 140, 142, 0.701961) 0px 0px 0px 100px inset; background-image: url('http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg');">
              <img src="http://www.ecdevelopment.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/hippie-flower.jpg" class="slideImg wp-post-image" alt="broadwayproject2"><span>Broadway Project</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really really appreciate what you did. It works when I run the snippet, but when I paste the CSS into my .css file it doesn't work like it does in the snippet. It just makes the text show up, not the white border on the inside which is all i need.

Comment: As I already mentioned, you need to recreate your problem here. [MCVE]. Your code is now `minimal`, but not yet `complete`, nor `verifiable`. Link the CSS files that apply in your environment. I can't override CSS I cannot see.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, there is a high chance that your CSS file contains errors that might affect browser's capacity to correctly apply the rules defined after the point of error. Link your CSS file, I'll check it and spot the error for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lIC3hDeH37 I have linked my style.css in there. Thank you so much.